# Is there a way to make a sphere made of equilateral triangles?

Tags: glass

I was wondering is there a way to make something like this in Blender?[image]

The real challenge though would be to texture it properly, cause I want to make it look like every triangle has a different color glass. Looking like a mosaic.
Any tips?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hmm, icosphere, wireframe, random per island colors? Give me ten minutes…

Comment: This kind of structure is called a [geodesic dome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic_dome), and it doesn't actually consist of equilateral triangles, they're only approximately equilateral. The only icosphere that's really equilateral is the icosahedron itself.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Create an Icosphere, duplicate and drop in the same place. Give one of the Icospheres a Wireframe modifier. Give the other an Edge Split modifier with an Edge Angle set to 0 and a Solidify modifier after the Edge Split.

[image]

[image]

Make a glass material for the Icosphere with the Solidify modifier. In the Shader Nodes tree, add a Geometry node and a ColourRamp and connect the Random Per Island to the Fac. Set the ColorRamp to a RGB Gradient by an extra point using the +  button, setting each point to red, green and blue. Then click the dropdown `v` and select Distribute Stops Evenly.

[image]

I placed a light inside for an effect. This is the result.

[image]

Comment: You can skip the duplication by putting the edge split modifier after the wire frame modifier on the same object, have two materials, and have the edge split modifier increment the material by one with “replace original” turned off.

Comment: I kept it separate for the Solidify modifier on the glass.

Comment: Hmm, fair point. Well, one can make it a little more efficient by using a linked duplicate instead. However, that would mean setting the materials to be attached to the object data instead of the mesh data.

Comment: I don't want to break the mood but the triangles of an icosphere are **not** all of equal surface : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nq4px.png (and thus not equilateral) but it does answer the body of the question :)

Comment: @Gorgious That's exactly right. You can project 4, 8, or 20 equilateral triangles onto a sphere. No other number works exactly. When you subdivide the icosahedron (the one with 20 triangles), the result is triangles that are only approximately equilateral. This might be enough for the OP?