# Is there a way to properly texture a spherical object like that?

Tags: texturing, modifiers, geometry

I was trying to make a spherical object like that to have like a mosaic texture ([Like in this tutorial](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/251927/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-sphere-made-of-equilateral-triangles)), but I have problem applying boolean modifier to separate two objects and texture them[image] properly. I'll include a blender file. Thank you in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As common_goldfish already mentioned:

1. switch to cycles + rendered view
2. add 2 boolean modifiers to cube.005:

[image]

i created a new sphere for that by basically just copying cube.004 and deleted the wireframe modifier and changed the size of it.

By that your inner sphere will be cut by the wireframe + these inner sphere so you really got split geometry so that random per island can work. You have to scale this inner sphere until it works as you want.

result:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

*Set Color ramp Material*

Follow the tutorial exactly using the edge split and solidify modifier.

Concentrate only on testing the inner sphere.

a. Use the color ramp with the distribute stops in the drop down menu.  Use a **principled BDSF** with a high transmission value.

b.Switch to render view in **Cycles**.

I am not sure that this material setting works as-is in Eevee.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but that's not exactly what I wanted to achieve. I want each of the holes to have different color. The edge split just divides then unevenly. Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, I am just thinking about that.  Yes.  You will need to have the geometry of the inner sphere copy the outer sphere.  I think it can be done.

Comment: You can boolean the objects, but you may have to simplify the modifier stack on one of them.